# If class Number is abstract why I'm I allowed to write Number n = 5?

Tags: java, numbers, wrapper

`Number n = new Number(5)` is illegal, but `Number n = 5` isn't. Why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because of autoboxing. `5` is not an object so it is wrapped into an object (`Integer` in this case), and `Integer` is a `Number`.

Comment: To verify this yourself just add System.out.println(n.getClass().getName());

Comment: The question was mainly about abstract classes.

Comment: No, it was about “how does `Number n = 5;` work if `Number` is abstract?” See above for how it does. :)

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, it's because `Number` is an abstract class - there **is** no constructor that corresponds to `Number(5)`, and even if there was you still would not be able to instantiate the class directly because it's abstract.

As Bombe explains, in your second case you're really creating an `Integer` object* - which, as a subclass of `Number`, can be assigned to such a variable.  And as it's a concrete class you can instantiate it.

*Although in practice it's actually more equivalent to `Integer.valueOf(5)`, which on Sun JREs won't create an additional Integer object but will use a pooled version (like the Flyweight pattern).

Comment: why it must be a static class?

Comment: +1 your answer is way better than Bombe's, he did not even use the word abstract in his answer, that's what the question was about

Comment: @Carlos - I meant *concrete* class, not static; I've fixed this typo ("thinko"?), thanks for pointing it out.  AFAIK there's no such thing as a static class per se (ignoring static inner classes which are a separate thing).

Answer (score 3):

It's similar to how the following would work:

```
List bob = new ArrayList();
```

List is an interface, so you can't instantiate it directly. However, you can declare a variable of type List and then assign to it a concrete object that implements that interface. Along the same lines, you can declare a variable of type Number and then assign to it any value object that is a concrete instance of that type. What you have done with the functional code is, for all intents and purposes (due to autoboxing):

```
Number n = new Integer(5);
```

Answer (score -2):

It shouldn't be. autoboxing is a big mistake.

Comment: I'd have to disagree.  int is the mistake.

The language would be simpler everything was defined as an Integer (or Long or whatever subclass of Number.)  Then let the compiler optimize it into an int (or whatever primitive.)  Of course it would have to handle == in sane manner.